# Adjust text within table using Tabulary

Tags: tables, width, fit, tabulary

**Problem:**

After looking into already existing threads about Tabulary, I could not find out what was wrong with the following code. The text does not adjust within the table.

**Code:**

```
\begin{table}[hbtp]
\footnotesize
\centering
\begin{tabulary}{1.0\textwidth}{L|L|L|L|L|L}
\hline
    \textbf{Level} & 
    \textbf{Technology} & 
    \textbf{People} & 
    \textbf{Activities} & 
    \textbf{Focus} & 
    \textbf{Function} \\
\hline
    Consensus-seeking & 
    Social and collaborative media designed for civic engagement & 
    Organizations & 
    Agree & 
    Goals & 
    Negotiated articulation, co-creation, consensus seeking \\  
\hline
\end{tabulary}
\caption{Caption starts here}
\label{XXX}
\end{table}
```

**Output:**

[image]

**Questions:**

(1) Why is it that the text does not adjust accordingly? The desired solution would be that the headers are 100% and text will adjust based on this.

(2) Why is it that some lines are more bolder than others? How to overcome this?

Comment: tabulary does not allocate any more importance to headers than the table body (often they should be less impotrtant when considering column widths) by default tex doesn't hyphenate teh first word of a paragraph so consensus and goals are overful (but you should set \tymin or use `l` columns to prevent those columns being squeezed

Comment: the rule thickness is an artifact of your pdf viewer, it has to snap the rules to pixel boundaries, so rounding errors can mean some are a pixel wider than others.

Comment: please always post complete documents not just fragments, so that people can easily test possible answers, in particular that would show the desired target width

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tabulary}
\begin{document}
\begin{table}[hbtp]
\footnotesize
\centering
\settowidth\tymin{\textbf{Activities}}
\setlength\extrarowheight{2pt}
\begin{tabulary}{1.0\textwidth}{L|L|L|L|L|L}
\hline
    \textbf{Level} & 
    \textbf{Technology} & 
    \textbf{People} & 
    \textbf{Activities} & 
    \textbf{Focus} & 
    \textbf{Function} \\
\hline
    Consensus-seeking & 
    Social and collaborative media designed for civic engagement & 
    Organizations & 
    Agree & 
    Goals & 
    Negotiated articulation, co-creation, consensus seeking \\  
\hline
\end{tabulary}
\caption{Caption starts here}
\label{XXX}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```